# Need Help using recursive grep search for only specific directories

Tags: php, bash, recursion, grep

I am hoping to do a grep search on a web server. 
The file structure for the multiple accounts is as follows

```
/home/user1/foo
..
/home/user1/public_html
/home/user2/foo
..
/home/user2/public_html
..
```

Instead of doing the search of /home/*, I only want to search /home/*/public_html/*

ls /home/*/public_html  would return the desired file list, but I want to do a one line grep operation.

The following was what I was thinking, but it doesn't work:

```
grep --include=\*.{php,phtml} -Rnw "home/*/public_html/" -e "raprap1"
```

What is the most efficient way to preform this query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use pipes?

```
ls /home/*/public_html | xargs grep "stringToFind"
```

Comment: I like your thinking, We are on to the right path. I had to make the results of ls display the full path and be more recursive.  
     `ls -d -1 /home/**/public_html/**/*.* | xargs grep "StringToFind"`

Comment: Yeah, I just used that for ls because yu said that part was finding all the files already. Glad you got it working.

Comment: So the final code, that allows for folders with white spaces in them is: `ls -d -1 /home/**/public_html/**/*.php | sed 's/.*/"&"/' 
 | xargs grep "searchString"`